# How to subtract a median only from integer value

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, lapply

I have this dataset

```
    df=structure(list(Dt = structure(1:39, .Label = c("2018-02-20 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-21 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-22 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-23 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-24 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-25 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-26 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-27 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-28 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-01 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-02 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-03 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-04 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-05 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-06 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-07 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-08 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-09 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-10 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-11 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-12 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-13 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-14 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-15 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-16 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-17 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-18 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-19 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-20 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-21 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-22 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-23 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-24 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-25 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-26 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-27 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-28 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-29 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-30 00:00:00.000"), class = "factor"), 
    ItemRelation = c(158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
    158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
    158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
    158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
    158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
    158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L), stuff = c(200L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3600L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    700L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1000L, 
    2600L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 700L), num = c(1459L, 
    1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
    1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
    1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
    1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
    1459L, 1459L), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), action = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Dt", "ItemRelation", 
"stuff", "num", "year", "action"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-39L))
```

The action column has only two values 0 and 1.
i must calculate median by stuff for 1 category of action,
then median by stuff of zero category of action, using last five integer values before one category.
 I just take the last 5 observations,
It is necessary to take the last 5 observations in the zero category of action, but only the integer values
in our case this is

```
200
3600
700
1000
2600
```

then substract median of zero category from median of one category.

The number of observations by stuff in the zero category of action can vary from 0-10.
If we have 10 integer values of zero category, we take last five.
If there is only 1,2,3,4,5 values integer,
 we subtract median of real number of integer values.
If we have only 0 without integer , we just substact 0.

How to do it?

## edit expected output

```
Dt                  ItemRelation    DocumentNum DocumentYear    value
2018-03-30 00:00:00.000 158043        1459       2018          -300
```

---

```
*-300=(700-median(   200,
    3600,
    700,
    1000,
    2600)
```

## note, if for 1 category of action by stuff there is one value(in our case it is 700) we don't calculate median, we work only with this value

if there are two values, we calculate median for 1 category by stuff

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: @RonakShah, i edited post,please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.0 <- df %>% filter(action == 0 & stuff != 0) %>% arrange(Dt) %>% top_n(5)
df.1 <- df %>% filter(action==1 & stuff!=0)

new.df <- rbind(df.0,df.1)


View(
  df %>% select (everything()) %>%  group_by(ItemRelation, num, year) %>%
    summarise(
      median.1 = median(stuff[action == 1 & stuff != 0], na.rm = T),
      median.0 = median(stuff[action == 0 &
                                stuff != 0], na.rm = T)
    ) %>%
    mutate(
      value = median.1 - median.0,
      DocumentNum = num,
      DocumentYear = year
    ) %>%
    select(ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear, value)
```

Does that help?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: it is work. One question.Does this code take into account what I wrote above? The fact that it can be more than one value for the stuff on the first category of the action, and then, if more than one value, then the median for the first category is calculated, after from it, median of zero category of stuff is subtracted?

Comment: i check it, it is work, but your code calculate the median by all obs of zero category of action, it must calculate the median by zero category but 5 last obs before one category. can you edit code?