# How to subtract a median only from 5 last integer values

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, lapply

I have this dataset

```
    df=structure(list(Dt = structure(1:39, .Label = c("2018-02-20 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-21 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-22 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-23 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-24 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-25 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-26 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-27 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-28 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-01 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-02 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-03 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-04 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-05 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-06 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-07 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-08 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-09 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-10 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-11 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-12 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-13 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-14 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-15 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-16 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-17 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-18 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-19 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-20 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-21 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-22 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-23 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-24 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-25 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-26 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-27 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-28 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-29 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-30 00:00:00.000"), class = "factor"), 
    ItemRelation = c(158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
    158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
    158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
    158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
    158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
    158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L), stuff = c(200L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3600L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    700L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1000L, 
    2600L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 700L), num = c(1459L, 
    1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
    1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
    1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
    1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
    1459L, 1459L), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), action = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Dt", "ItemRelation", 
"stuff", "num", "year", "action"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-39L))
```

The action column has only two values 0 and 1. i must calculate median by stuff for 1 category of action, then median by stuff of zero category of action, using last five integer values before one category. I just take the last 5 observations, It is necessary to take the last 5 observations in the zero category of action, but only the integer value, and not calculate the median
by all values of zero category. In our case this is

```
200
3600
700
1000
2600
```

then substract median of zero category from median of one category.

The number of observations by stuff in the zero category of action can vary from 0-10. If we have 10 integer values of zero category, we take last five. If there is only 1,2,3,4,5 values integer, we subtract median of real number of integer values. If we have only 0 without integer , we just substact 0.

this solution of  Akshay  from adjacent topic [How to subtract a median only from integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908897/how-to-subtract-a-median-only-from-integer-value/50910327#50910327) helped me

```
df.0 <- df %>% filter(action == 0 & stuff != 0) %>% arrange(Dt) %>% top_n(5)
df.1 <- df %>% filter(action==1 & stuff!=0)

new.df <- rbind(df.0,df.1)


View(
  df %>% select (everything()) %>%  group_by(ItemRelation, num, year) %>%
    summarise(
      median.1 = median(stuff[action == 1 & stuff != 0], na.rm = T),
      median.0 = median(stuff[action == 0 &
                                stuff != 0], na.rm = T)
    ) %>%
    mutate(
      value = median.1 - median.0,
      DocumentNum = num,
      DocumentYear = year
    ) %>%
    select(ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear, value)
```

But code calculate the median by all obs of zero category of action, it must calculate the median by zero category, but 5 last obs before one category.

If anybody help me in original , i.e. adjacent topic, i ll just delete this new topic,not to produce related topics.

## Note, instead of zeros, there may be other values for the zero category of action.

## Edit2 i added new category- CustomerName

out

```
put <- data.frame(mydat[which.max(as.Date(mydat$Dt)),
                           c("CustomerName","ItemRelation","DocumentNum","DocumentYear")], 
                     value = m,
                     row.names = 1:length(which.max(as.Date(mydat$Dt))))


CustomerName ItemRelation DocumentNum DocumentYear value
1  orange TC       157214        1529         2018   162
```

why i get the only for one string?
output must be  as example. there are many stratum.not one

```
CustomerName ItemRelation DocumentNum DocumentYear value
1  orange TC       157214        1529         2018   162
2  appleTC              5        1529         2018   164
```

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly: You want to subset your data by `action (1 or 2)` and then by `stuff (!=0)` and then take the corresponding median, to finally perform arithmetic operations using those two values?

Comment: @nate.edwinton. The action has only 0 or 1 category. I want calculate median by stuff for last 5 obs. of zero category of action.  we take 5 observations previous  the first category of the action by stuff (only more than zero), we calculate  the median, then subtract it median from the median for the first category of the action. Do you understand me? This code calculate the common median for the zero category of action by stuff

Comment: Do you want to first subset `stuff / action` for "more than zero / zero" and then take the last 5 observations, or first take the last 5 observations and then subset? Also, when calculating the median for `action = 1`, do you also consider only specific observations (last 5, or more than zero)?

Comment: @nate.edwinton "Do you want to first subset stuff / action for "more than zero / zero" and then take the last 5 observations"- YES . Action=1 can have any number of observations. but zeros and negative values must be removed from the stuff of the first category of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear to me what exactly you whish to accomplish. However, that might be of help.

You can subset the part of the data you need using `which` and `intersect`:

```
# df with action 0 and stuff > 0
v <- df$stuff[intersect(which(df$action == 0),
                        which(df$stuff > 0))]

# df with action 1 and stuff > 0
w <- df$stuff[intersect(which(df$action == 1),
                        which(df$stuff > 0))]
```

`v` contains all elements of `stuff` where `action` is `0` and `stuff` is not `0`. From here on now, calculating the median is a formality. (You might want to add safety measures in case `intersect(...)` is empty, e.g. if `stuff` is always `0` when `action` is `0`).

```
# calulating the median of v for the last 5 observations
l <- length(v)
m0 <- median(v[(l-4):l]) # taking the median of the last 5 observations
# computing the final difference
m <- median(w) - m0
```

---

**Edit**

To reproduce the above out put, consider

```
output <- data.frame(df[which.max(as.Date(df$Dt)),
                        c("Dt","ItemRelation","num","year")], 
                     value = m,
                     row.names = 1:length(which.max(as.Date(df$Dt))))
```

where `which.max(as.Date(df$Dt))` gives the row number of the latest date. However, the logic you are applying to get that result might differ so caution is advised here.

Anyway, here it the output

```
> output
                       Dt ItemRelation  num year value
1 2018-03-30 00:00:00.000       158043 1459 2018  -300
```

Comment: nate.edwinton, i edited my post. Can you provide this output, as i edited, course ItemRelation    DocumentNum DocumentYear is needed for me category. the result must for each category of  ItemRelation    DocumentNum DocumentYear

Comment: in other words, your code should work in strata Itemrelation + DocumentNum+DocumentYear

Comment: I mistakenly put dt, it is not needed.

Comment: @D.Joe Note that `which.max` returns only the first instance where maximum is met **not** all instances (see `which.max(c(1:2,2))` vs `which(c(1:2,2) == max(c(1:2,2)))` ). So - depending on your needs - it might be safer to replace `which.max(as.Date(df$Dt))` with `which(as.Date(df$Dt) == max(as.Date(df$Dt)))`.

Comment: i did it.  and got the error > output <- data.frame(mydat[which(as.Date(mydat$Dt) == max(as.Date(mydat$Dt),
+                            c("CustomerName","ItemRelation","DocumentNum","DocumentYear")], 
Error: unexpected ']' in:
"output <- data.frame(mydat[which(as.Date(mydat$Dt) == max(as.Date(mydat$Dt),
                           c("CustomerName","ItemRelation","DocumentNum","DocumentYear")]"
>                      value = m,
Error: unexpected ',' in "                     value = m,"
>                      row.names = 1:length(which(as.Date(mydat$Dt) == max(as.Date(mydat$Dt)))))))

Comment: m is median for all category at once, i need calculate for each category.

Comment: output <- data.frame(mydat[,
                           c("CustomerName","ItemRelation","DocumentNum","DocumentYear")], 
                     value = m)  it is works

Comment: but i get but for all strata I have the same value for value. Do you understand what i about. your code here # df with action 0 and stuff > 0
v <- df$stuff[intersect(which(df$action == 0),
                        which(df$stuff > 0))]

# df with action 1 and stuff > 0
w <- df$stuff[intersect(which(df$action == 1),
                        which(df$stuff > 0))] calculate for all stratum and not for each separately